# Pausing & Running External Commands in B/w String Decompression

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Greetings to respected members...I was using the following function for compressing multiple files but on extraction I need to run an external program.

There are two ways to it, first, wait for complete extraction, which is pretty slow, So, can you please help me guys, so that, on extracting n number of files, the extraction pauses, & runs a code part like begin & end & then resume, then again pause after n files & repeat the process.

```
uses
  Zlib;

procedure CompressFiles(Files : TStrings; const Filename : String);
var
  infile, outfile, tmpFile : TFileStream;
  compr : TCompressionStream;
  i,l : Integer;
  s : String;

begin
  if Files.Count > 0 then
  begin
    outFile := TFileStream.Create(Filename,fmCreate);
    try
      { the number of files }
      l := Files.Count;
      outfile.Write(l,SizeOf(l));
      for i := 0 to Files.Count-1 do
      begin
        infile := TFileStream.Create(Files[i],fmOpenRead);
        try
          { the original filename }
          s := ExtractFilename(Files[i]);
          l := Length(s);
          outfile.Write(l,SizeOf(l));
          outfile.Write(s[1],l);
          { the original filesize }
          l := infile.Size;
          outfile.Write(l,SizeOf(l));
          { compress and store the file temporary}
          tmpFile := TFileStream.Create('tmp',fmCreate);
          compr := TCompressionStream.Create(clMax,tmpfile);
          try
            compr.CopyFrom(infile,l);
          finally
            compr.Free;
            tmpFile.Free;
          end;
          { append the compressed file to the destination file }
          tmpFile := TFileStream.Create('tmp',fmOpenRead);
          try
            outfile.CopyFrom(tmpFile,0);
          finally
            tmpFile.Free;
          end;
        finally
          infile.Free;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      outfile.Free;
    end;
    DeleteFile('tmp');
  end;
end;

procedure DecompressFiles(const Filename, DestDirectory : String);
var
  dest,s : String;
  decompr : TDecompressionStream;
  infile, outfile : TFilestream;
  i,l,c : Integer;
begin
  // IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter (D6/D7 only)
  dest := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(DestDirectory);

  infile := TFileStream.Create(Filename,fmOpenRead);
  try
    { number of files }
    infile.Read(c,SizeOf(c));
    for i := 1 to c do
    begin
      { read filename }
      infile.Read(l,SizeOf(l));
      SetLength(s,l);
      infile.Read(s[1],l);
      { read filesize }
      infile.Read(l,SizeOf(l));
      { decompress the files and store it }
      s := dest+s; //include the path
      outfile := TFileStream.Create(s,fmCreate);
      decompr := TDecompressionStream.Create(infile);
      try
        outfile.CopyFrom(decompr,l);
      finally
        outfile.Free;
        decompr.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    infile.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you want to perform actions before the entire file has been decompressed, you'll need to invoke those actions inside your loop. Sounds like a perfect opportunity for parallelisation.

Comment: OP said *"every n files"*, so not before a file has been decompressed but after every Nth complete decompression.  OP also seemed quite clear that decompression should pause while the external command runs.  Rather than parallelisation this sounds like a perfect job for a simple "WinExecAndWait", or similar.

Comment: @Deltics Asker presumably isn't clear on what is the best way forward. Waiting is just going to slow things down even more.

Comment: Waiting will fasten things up...Also, if I say that decompression module is working on a string of Deflate Streams, then, its also saving disk :D

Comment: No. Waiting will slow you down.

Comment: Alright respected master....For this I have started to read about Tthreads...So, lees information is available about it...Wanna learn more....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an action after every *n* iterations of the loop, simply check whether the number of iterations so far is a multiple of *n*. You have the current iteration number in your variable `i`, so use that to augment your loop as follows:

```
for i := 1 to c do
begin
  ... // existing contents of the loop can go here.
  if (i mod n) = 0 then begin
    // TODO: Run external program here.
  end;
end;
```